# Python solve optimization problem by choosing items from two dictionaries/lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

I am relatively new to mathematical optimization problems, but the closest topic to my current problem might be called **discrete optimization** (correct me if I am wrong).

Basically, I have 2 separate dictionaries of items, each item having a list of attributes, we can call them by numbers from 1 to 6. I have to choose items from both dictionaries to solve the maximization problem for one specific attribute (let's say number 1) and with several constraints for each attribute. The number of items I can choose from each dictionary is also a constraint on its own.

Here is an example of dictionaries I am talking about:

```
# Dictionaries, as an example (in my case each dict can have 100s and even 1000s of items)

dict_a = {"12312321":[321,5422.555,True,5893,3891,-122],
    "492391":[5531,1531.1,False,21003,-5293,23],
    "892781145":[89234,73110147.892121,True,152,5321,315124]}
dict_b = {"3789213451":[51231,5422.52,False,214383,32823,545622],
    "48123":[5531,123131.13212,False,26243,5223,52233],
    "4981093727":[894,7198347.5321,False,12312,-21,4],
    "23":[801123,12234283.05114,False,32113,34131245,212312]}
```

**Constraints** might be:

- Attribute 3 must be False (in items from both dicts)
- Attribute 2 must be between 1000 and 100000 (in items from both dicts)
- Sum of attributes 4 from items in Dict A divided by the sum of attributes 4 from items in Dict B must be >= 1.15
- You can pick max of 2 items and min of 2 items from Dict A
- You can pick max of 4 items and min of 1 item from Dict B
- Sum of attributes 5 from items in Dict B must be more than a sum of the same attributes in Dict A

And let's say **the goal** is to select certain items from each dict to maximize for:

- Sum of attributes 1 from items in Dict A, minus a sum of attributes 1 from items in Dict B.

I am not asking to solve the problem for me or create a ready-to-go formula. I would like to know how to approach the following problem the best way, considering I am relatively new to optimization problems and don't know 10 different formulas to do so. I am planning to use the SciPy library since it works the best in my opinion, however, feel free to recommend other Python libraries that can tackle the problem.

Many thanks!

Comment: "Attribute 3 must be False (in items from both dicts)" I can't see any boolean value in a dictionary and what have you tried so far? You have all the information you need what is stopping you from writing the code

Comment: It is in the form of 1 and 0, but let me re-format it for easier understanding. @deadshot

Comment: @deadshot Well, I would like to know what type of problem I am dealing with at first. Is it discrete linear optimization, something else? There is a huge mass of various optimization problems in math, and I am not sure how mine is called.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming Seems you indeed need LP. As I can see all contraints and objective are linear. There are open-source solvers, which work well on smaller sets of problems.

Comment: https://docs.python-mip.com/en/latest/examples.html Seems a good start to get familiar with (Mixed)Integer Programming.

Comment: Still interested in more code-guided solution?